# I have a asmx webservice , I want to return the xml from a stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, web-services, asmx

Im using Linq to SQL I have a stored procedure that is returning xml . ie im using for xml outo ,elements

that works fine.  what I want to do is expose the result of the stored procedure via a webservice.

Here is some pseudo code:  if some could help me replace the ?'s

```
[WebMethod]
public ?  myMethod( int custID)
{
    var myCust = db.getCustomer(custID) ;

    return ?
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `db.getCustomer(custID)`?

Comment: You could always pass it back as a string..... or the better choice probably would be to *not* convert it to XML, but rather return a real `Customer` object from LINQ and then pass that object back to the caller....

Answer (score 0):

You can return either `XmlElement` or `XElement`.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was it was a stored proc returning a xml data set,

the solution is extremely simple I simply created a List

and returned it.  I was kind of surprised because i assumed List<>  needed a defined class.
it just used the result set so Im pretty happy. now if someone could point me in the right direction so I could edit the contents of the List< > to replace the name of the parent tags I'd be super happy.